# can't add all the selected rows to the dataset

Tags: asp.net, datatable, dataset

I have added records chosen (`checkbox`) in a `datatable` shown below, records have been displaying in a `datagrid` populated using `stored procedure`. Then on the `button click` I `save` all the selected (added) records to the `ds` in `database`.

```
public DataSet getMain()
    {
        DataSet ds = CFObj.GetSchemaRequest();
        DataRow dr;
        dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < dgAvailableCandidates.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox saveChkBoxItem = (CheckBox)dgAvailableCandidates.Items[i].FindControl("chkbox_SelectCandidate");
            if (saveChkBoxItem.Checked)
            {
                //ds.Tables[0].Columns["pk_scrndRecId"].ReadOnly = false;
                dr["pk_scrndRecId"] = "0";
                dr["fk_jobId"] = ddl_jobList.SelectedValue.ToString();
                obj._fkjob_Id = ddl_jobList.SelectedValue.ToString();
                dr["fk_recId"] = dgAvailableCandidates.DataKeys[i].ToString();
                obj._fk_recId = dgAvailableCandidates.DataKeys[i].ToString();
            }

        }
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
        return ds;
    }
```

here my issue is when `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);` i put outside of loop, it adds only one last selected record to `ds`, and when I put this inside `loop`, it throws following `exception`

> [pk_scrndRecId] column is read only

and when I have placed this inside `if` block, it throws following `exception`:

> This row already belongs to this table.

I am not able to understand why this code doesn't add all the selected rows of `datagrid` to the `ds`.

please help. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new row and add it to datatable **inside the loop** and so each time it will create a new instance and add it to your datatable.

Check updated code.

```
public DataSet getMain()
{
    DataSet ds = CFObj.GetSchemaRequest();
    DataRow dr;
    for (int i = 0; i < dgAvailableCandidates.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox saveChkBoxItem = (CheckBox)dgAvailableCandidates.Items[i].FindControl("chkbox_SelectCandidate");
        if (saveChkBoxItem.Checked)
        {
            dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            //ds.Tables[0].Columns["pk_scrndRecId"].ReadOnly = false;
            dr["pk_scrndRecId"] = "0";
            dr["fk_jobId"] = ddl_jobList.SelectedValue.ToString();
            obj._fkjob_Id = ddl_jobList.SelectedValue.ToString();
            dr["fk_recId"] = dgAvailableCandidates.DataKeys[i].ToString();
            obj._fk_recId = dgAvailableCandidates.DataKeys[i].ToString();
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }

    return ds;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the guidance, first. Would you please post a nice link to improve my conceptual understanding of datatable (or ado net) thanks!